# Execute new instance of class extends AsyncTask multiple times

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my class who extend the AsyncTask. The logic is I take a screenshot of the camera preview each seconds with an interval, and each second in this interval, I create a new instance of my class extending AsyncTask and call execute on it without stock it in a variable. But when I set a Log.d in my doInBackground() method in my class, the Log.d is called only one time in the first second of the interval. I need to do that to send a new screenshot each second to a socket server.

This is the interval code :

```
private void startTakingPicturesInterval() {
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureScreenTaked);
            Log.d("debug_app", "Picture Taked");
            new ClientServerStream().execute(image_to_send_captured_each_time);
        }
    },0,1000);
}

private Camera.PictureCallback pictureScreenTaked = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        image_to_send_captured_each_time = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        ImageView img_result_test = findViewById(R.id.img_result_test);
        img_result_test.setImageBitmap(image_to_send_captured_each_time);
        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        camera.startPreview();
    }
};
```

My method doInBackground of the class extending the AsyncTask :

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    initValues();
    Log.d("debug_app", "Client executed correctly");
    try {
        bw.write("test");
        bw.flush();

        closeAll();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Solution Finded**

The solution is because my server socket was disonnected so probably there was an error in my Client Socket so the code doesn't execute and the error is not shown because they executed Asychronously

Comment: "I have a problem with my class who extend the AsyncTask" -- `AsyncTask` has been deprecated for a while. "I create a new instance of my class extending AsyncTask and call execute on it without stock it in a variable" -- since your `TimerTask`'s `run()` method is called on a background thread, why do you need an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: I found the problem thank's !